# WebGL -Trying to texture a square, but it won't work for some reason

Tags: 2d, webgl, textures

So I am in dire need of a code read through, if someone would be so kind- I have no idea where a fault can come from- I've been comparing this code to the code from the tutorial here:

http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson05/index.html

and have looked through both about 10 times- I just don't know...Need some help from the pros... Just trying to texture a square, without any of the 3d stuff that I don't care for at the moment-

```
    <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    uniform sampler2D uSampler;

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));

       // gl_FragColor= vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    </script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;


    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    }
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var gl;
function initGL(canvas) {
    try {
        gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
        gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
        gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
    } catch (e) {
    }
    if (!gl) {
        alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
    }
}


function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!shaderScript) {
        return null;
    }

    var str = "";
    var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
    while (k) {
        if (k.nodeType == 3) {
            str += k.textContent;
        }
        k = k.nextSibling;
    }

    var shader;
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}


var shaderProgram;

function initShaders() {
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);


    shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute=gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute); //**

    shaderProgram.samplerUniform= gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");



    shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
}


var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
var pMatrix = mat4.create();

function setMatrixUniforms() {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
}



var triangleVertexPositionBuffer;
var squareVertexPositionBuffer;

function initBuffers() {


    squareVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
    vertices = [
         1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  0.0
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 4;



    squareTexPositionBuffer=gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareTexPositionBuffer);

    texvert= [1.0, 0.0,
              0.0, 0.0,
              1.0, 1.0,
              0.0, 1.0];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(texvert), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    squareTexPositionBuffer.itemSize=2;
    squareTexPositionBuffer.numItems=4;




}


function drawScene() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-2.0, 0.0, -7.0]);


    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [3.0, 0.0, 0.0]);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareTexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, squareTexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, neheTexture);
    gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);






    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);


}


function handleLoadedTexture(texture) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}



var neheTexture;

function initTexture(){



    neheTexture = gl.createTexture();
    neheTexture.image = new Image();
    neheTexture.image.onload = function() {
        handleLoadedTexture(neheTexture)
    }

    neheTexture.image.src = "nehe.gif";

}


function webGLStart() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("lesson01-canvas");
    initGL(canvas);
    initShaders();
    initBuffers();
    initTexture();

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    drawScene();
}


</script>
```

Comment: Are you working on your computer or on server? If square exists but is simply black, try: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally Code seems to be okay, you could also only write `texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);`

Comment: I am running this locally- but WebGL works fine

Comment: Just tried changed the texture2D- still doesn't work

Comment: Make sure you haven't run into the stupid cross domain policy restriction that sometimes won't let you load textures from your local disk. Testing it on a server can help you erase that potential point of failure. There should be a warning in console, also.

Answer (score 1):

Texture won't be loaded immediately.
This is not a problem when you have an animation, because the scene will be rendered with blank texture while it's not fully loaded, and once it is the objects will become textured. You don't have animation, only one drawing call, that executes before fully loading image.
So after you load image you should make another drawing call, so the scene is drawn with texture.

So something like:

```
neheTexture.image.onload = function() {
    handleLoadedTexture(neheTexture);
    drawScene(); // <- now draw scene again, once I got my texture
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's kind of a follow up question- Let's say I wanted to have two different shapes- one with a color buffer and another with a texture buffer, how woud I write that code out in the shaders since the tutorials made it almost like you could only have one or the other, but not both?

So like in the following code, I have something for the texture and something to make the color blue in another line of code- how would I make that differentiation in this language- I tried using ints to symbolize the choice between the two but it didn't work out very well...

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
     precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));

   // gl_FragColor= vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
</script>
```

Comment: only one question per topic.
it's stackoverflow's nature to give multiple answers to one question and choose best, it's not meant to be with multiple questions.
if you're satisfied with answer for first question, accept and upvote answer and then open new topic and ask another question.